# Dirty form with no dirty fields on CRM 2015 online

Tags: crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2015

We have migrated to CRM 2015 online, and we are experiencing an issues with Completed Phone Calls.
When we open the form of one of those click for instance on the description field (that is a textarea) and then close it, we get prompted with a text message that says "Your changes have not been saved. To stay on the page so that you can save your changes, click Cancel."

We have no code running on that field, nor is the text changing.
I assume there is some indentation/new line/carriage optimizing running on the form, but it is bothering us.

We have autosave on, and we would like to keep it on. I know I could solve it by forcing autosave, but do we have to do it for every field where this is happening?

Comment: You didn't explicitly say - is there any code running on the Load of the form or on the "Retrieve" plugin?  Is this only for completed phone calls?  or any phone calls?  If open phone calls are doing the same thing, you could easily figure out the culprit by opening the form and hitting save - then viewing the audit history.

Answer (score 4):

You should look to see which field(s) are considered dirty fields.  You can do that if using Internet Explorer opening your Completed phone call in CRM and then pressing F12 to open the developer tools and then click on the Debugger tab/section depending on which version you are using.  In the console window, add this line, which should show which fields CRM considers as "dirty" fields - 
     `alert(Xrm.Page.data.entity.getDataXml());`

You can also use a small bit of JavaScript that grabs this info and copies it to the clipboard for you using the window.prompt function as shown in the code below (and that can be run from the Browser debugger console window).

Just to confirm I've got your scenario correct, you are only seeing this when clicking in the description field of a completed phone call?

```
var dirtyFields = frames[0].Xrm.Page.data.entity.getDataXml();
window.prompt("Copy dirty fields to clipboard: Ctrl+C,Enter",dirtyFields);
```

This way you should be able to at least see what's causing the fields to be considered to be dirty.

Is this with the new CRM 2015 Spring Release, Update 1, or the original CRM 2015 online release?  You should be able to see a version number if you click on the CRM Settings icon in the top right and then select About to see the version number.

I am editing this (3/22/2016) to reflect that you can also see dirty fields with this JavaScript bookmarklet (either run from a favorite in the favorites bar or entered as one line on the address bar immediately after opening the Microsoft CRM Record in question).  I would run both of these to determine which fields are dirty.  I got this from http://blog.sonomapartners.com/2011/10/trying-to-catch-my-form-ridin-dirty-.html and have tested it with Internet Explorer and a Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2015 deployment, but it should work in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013, 2015 and 2016 as well.  One other thing mentioned is that if a CRM field that is used in a lookup has multiple consecutive spaces in the value, that it could cause the dirty field notification to be triggered, i.e. "Chad     Rexin" vs. "Chad Rexin"

```
javascript:var message="The following fields are dirty: \n";window.frames[0].Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.forEach(function(attribute,index){if(attribute.getIsDirty()==true){message+="\u2219 "+attribute.getName()+"\n";}});alert(message);
```

Comment: I'm in a similar boat. I tried the javascript listed and get "<opportunity></opportunity>" as a response. I purposefully made a field dirty, and that field shows up between the tags. I force a save, and it still tells me I need to save when navigating away. Thoughts?